# Creating id variable based on specific string in tow columns

Tags: r, loops, variables, group

I want to create a tourID that separates trips started from home and ended to home. Following is an example of my data.

| personID | TripID | satartpurpose | endpurpose |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | home | shopping |
| 1 | 2 | shopping | home |
| 2 | 1 | home | work |
| 2 | 2 | work | home |
| 2 | 3 | home | visit friend |
| 2 | 4 | visit friend | home |

So, the final output would be as below:

| personID | TripID | startpurpose | endpurpose | tourID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | home | shopping | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | shopping | home | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | home | work | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | work | home | 2 |
| 2 | 3 | home | visit friend | 3 |
| 2 | 4 | visit friend | home | 3 |

I am new to r and don't know how I can write the code for this. I really appreciate if someone can help me.

Thanks so much,
Tina

Answer (score 0):

Since the first observation for tourID occurs when startpurpose == "home", only keep those rows. Create the tourID based on the `row_number`. Merge back with the rest of the data. Then fill in the rest of the tourID:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

my_df <- data.frame(
matrix(
  c(
    1,1,"home", "shopping",
    1,2,"shopping", "home",
    2,1,"home","work",
    2,2,"work","home",
    2,3,"home","visit friend",
    2,4,"visit friend","home"
  ),
  nrow = 6,
  ncol = 4,
  byrow = TRUE,
  dimnames = list(NULL,
                  c("personID", "TripID", "startpurpose", "endpurpose"))
),
stringsAsFactors = FALSE
) %>% 
  mutate(personID = as.numeric(personID),
         TripID = as.numeric(TripID))

my_df_id <- my_df %>% 
  filter(startpurpose == "home") %>% 
  mutate(tourID = row_number()) %>% 
  merge(my_df,
        all = TRUE) %>% 
  fill(tourID)
```